# homestead up:The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

system:windows10  10240

vagrant:1.7.4

virtualbox:5.0.2

and I have tried virtualbox4.3.30,4.3.28,...4.3.12, When I run `homestead up` , it fails with the same error message:

```
C:\Windows\system32>homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network.
```

This is my Homestead.yaml file

```
    ---
ip: "192.168.0.15"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:/wnmp/www
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Answer (score 3):

Try different IP like 10.0.0.X